# I retired from a job and went back a year later as a contractor. How do I list both stints without duplicating the responsibilities?

Tags: resume, contracting

For years I worked directly for a large company.  After retiring I worked three years for a company who contracted me to a second company, who contracted me back to the original company doing the same job. I don't want to make it look like I continually worked for the company I retired from and there is a gap in service.  How do I list both employers without duplicating the responsibilities and accomplishments?

Answer (score 5):

Just say that you were doing the same work as a consultant that you did as a full time employee.

> **2014-2017  ABC Consulting**
>
> Continued to support the same functions for XYZ co that I did while working for them directly.
>
> **2001-2013 XYZ Co**
>
> Responsible for [all details go here]...

Or if your most recent employer isn't obviously a consulting company:

> **2014-2017  ABC Co**
>
> Consulted for XYZ Co and continued to support the same functions that I did while working for them directly.
>
> **2001-2013 XYZ Co**
>
> Responsible for [all details go here]...

Answer (score 4):

You list your employment using the name of the company sending you paychecks.  So even though you were on site at your former employer, you're working for the consulting company.

The tricky part is that you did do the same job with the same responsibility.  I don't think that's necessarily bad though, a career is focus in one area.